Apparent contradiction: conditional depends on x, but resulting joint suggests independence
Consider some distribution over $x, x'$ (each in $\mathbb{R}^d$), with the following properties:

The distribution is symmetric, i.e $p(x), p(x')$ have the same form
The marginals have mean $0$ and rank $k$ covariance $VV^\top$
$x'|x$ is distributed with mean $0$ and covariance $xx^\top$

Now assume as well that the conditionals and marginals are Gaussians, so $x \sim \mathcal{N}(0, VV^\top)$ and $x'|x \sim \mathcal{N}(0, xx^\top)$. Then the joint distribution should also be Gaussian, and we only need to determine the cross covariance to define the entire distribution:
$$\mathbb{E}[xx'^\top] = \mathbb{E}[x \ \mathbb{E}[x'|x]^\top] = \mathbf{0_{d \times d}}$$ where we get the 0 matrix since $\mathbb{E}[x'|x] = 0$. This gives
$$(x, x') \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}VV^\top & 0 \\ 0 & VV^\top\end{bmatrix}\right)$$
But then the zero cross covariance between jointly Gaussian $x, x'$ suggests they are independent. This seems off to me, since we started off with the fact that $x'|x$ clearly seems to depend on $x$: we had $x'|x \sim \mathcal{N}(0, xx^\top)$. If they were independent, wouldn't the conditional distribution evaluate to $p(x'|x) = p(x') = p(x)$, (second equality by symmetry), which would imply $x'|x \sim \mathcal{N}(0, VV^\top)$?
What am I missing here? Where did I go wrong with my reasoning?
On a tangent, my goal was to find possible distributions that fit these criteria. If we drop the assumption that the distributions are normal, how would one go about finding such distributions?

Let's make our life simple and assume $d=1,.$ By your assumptions the PDF of $x$ is $$\tfrac1{\sqrt{2\pi V^2}}\exp\left(-\tfrac{x^2}{2V^2}\right),$$ and that of $x'|x$ is $$\tfrac1{\sqrt{2\pi x^2}}\exp\left(-\tfrac{(x')^2}{2x^2}\right),.$$ Removing $|x$ we also see that this is the joint PDF of $(x,x'),.$ Can you tell me how this can possibly be Gaussian?

I'm not sure I follow how removing $|x$ gives us the joint PDF of $(x, x')$. I've tried multiplying the two distributions together to get $$\frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{V^2x^2}} \exp\left(-\left(\frac{x^2}{2V^2} + \frac{x'^2}{2x^2}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2\pi |\Sigma|^{1/2}} \exp\left(-(x, x')^\top \Sigma (x, x')\right)$$
with $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}V^2 & 0 \ 0 & x^2\end{bmatrix}$, which I admit I'm not sure how I could write the exponential term as a quadratic product where the covariance doesn't depend on $x$. Is this what you meant by it not possibly being Gaussian?

In the comments you are right regarding "removing" $|x$ so let me revise.
To simplify notation I write $y=x'\,.$
You want
$$f(y|x)=\frac{f(y,x)}{f(x)}$$ to be Gaussian with variance $x^2\,.$ This means $$\frac{f(y,x)}{f(x)}=\tfrac1{\sqrt{2\pi x^2}}\exp\left(-\tfrac{y^2}{2x^2}\right)\,.$$
Claim: There is no univariate PDF $f(x)$ that makes
$$
f(y,x)=\tfrac1{\sqrt{2\pi x^2}}\exp\left(-\tfrac{y^2}{2x^2}\right)f(x)
$$
jointly Gaussian, that is, equal to
$$
\frac1{2\pi\sigma\tau\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left(-\tfrac{y^2\sigma^2-2yx\sigma\tau\rho+x^2\tau^2}{2(1-\rho^2)\sigma^2\tau^2}\right)\,.
$$
for some standard deviations $\sigma,\tau>0$ and a correlation $\rho\in(-1,1)\,.$
Proof. If that $f(x)$ exists we could write it as $f(x)=g(x)e^{-h(x)}$ where $g(x)$ is proportional to $\sqrt{2\pi x^2}$ (which is good) but $h(x)$ has to satisfy
$$
\frac{y^2}{2x^2}+h(x)=\frac{y^2\sigma^2-2yx\sigma\tau\rho+x^2\tau^2}{2(1-\rho^2)\sigma^2\tau^2}\,.
$$
That is:
$$
h(x)=\frac{y^2x^2\sigma^2-y^2(1-\rho^2)\sigma^2\tau^2-2yx^3\sigma\tau\rho+x^4\tau^2}{2(1-\rho^2)\sigma^2\tau^2x^2}\,.
$$
The RHS is a function of $x$ only if and only if the partial derivative w.r.t. $y$ vanishes:
$$
2yx^2\sigma^2-2y(1-\rho^2)\sigma^2\tau^2-2x^3\sigma\tau\rho\equiv 0\,.
$$
Seen as a polynomial in $x$ this vanishes if and only if all its coefficients vanish:
$$
2y\sigma^2=0\,,\quad 2y(1-\rho^2)\sigma^2\tau^2=0\,,\quad 2\sigma\tau\rho=0\,. 
$$
Since this must hold for all $y$ we must have $\sigma=0$ wich makes the joint Gaussian $f(y,x)$ degenerate.
$$\tag*{$\Box$}
\quad
$$
